# How to detect mobile user agent and apply CSS/template accordingly?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css, mobile-web-design

I need to be able to initiate differently couple of CSS elements if the user is browsing the website with "mobile" user agent.

To improve the mobile browsing experience.

I am not looking for "hidden-phone" viewport tricks.

I'd like to be able to either make some CSS elements only display when mobile user agent is detected, OR have like two templates, and that one would load for desktop and one for mobile.

The idea that this is possible comes from seeing other websites that have both mobile and desktop versions, some of them need user to click something to change that layout and others auto-detect it.

Doable in Joomla? How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [mobilejoomla](http://www.mobilejoomla.com/) which is an extension dedicated to mobile, I had used it in the early versions and was ok.

Another way is to configure your template to detect mobile devices by means of scripts like [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) or [detectmobilebrowsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) and adapt accordingly.

A third way is the extension Advanced Module Manager described in this [question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-can-a-module-be-disabled-based-on-device-or-viewport-size-in-joomla-3-to-opt?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I'm not sure about mobilejoomla, I checked their site but I worry they'd change the whole template just to make things work? I'm on my custom template so I wouldn't want that. Ads for free and why'd I pay when this should be normal thing done in Joom? Pass...

I will go with mobiledetect and see the results.

Comment: That's why I mentioned all the possible ways ;) . Glad I helped.

Comment: was trying the manual mobiledetect... but I'm not in my top concentration now to attempt it without step by step instructions and examples didn't really "speak to me". But I found this, a Joomla plugin for mobiledetect. Might be of use to someone: [link](http://www.yagendoo.com/en/blog/free-mobile-detection-plugin-for-joomla.html) from yagendoo.

Comment: and here's another one, with muuuch better documentation:
[link](http://www.joomla-specialist.net/joomla-extensions/joomla-simple-mobile-detection.html)